# Make empty divs do the same height of absolute content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a wrapper in relative position with three div. I want to use two of them as a background one on the left side and the other one on the right side (I use materializecss grid).

The third div is in absolute position I want to use it to display content hover the two first divs.

I want the empty divs with background colours to be the same height as the absolute div with content.

I tried to give a `height:100vh;` to the first two divs but I want this divs fits the entire page (not only the visible part) even if the content in the third div is longer than the viewport.

Anyone know how to do that ? Do I need Javascript ?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.col.s8.leftside {
  background: #E3B2B0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col.s4.rightside {
  background: #D27156;
  height: 100vh;
}

.article {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Leftside background -->
  <div class="col s8 leftside">
  </div>
  <!-- Rightside background -->
  <div class="col s4 rightside">
  </div>
  <!-- Article -->
  <div class="col s6 offset-s3 article">
    <a href="<?php echo $page->permalink(); ?>">
      <h4>
        <?php echo $page->title(); ?>
      </h4>
    </a>
    <?php if ($page->coverImage()) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $page->coverImage(); ?>" />
    <?php endif ?>
    <!-- Full content -->
    <?php echo $page->content(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If those background divs are supposed to be background (and have the same height as content div), wouldn't it make more sense to absolute position them, instead of content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to checkout here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/loicelthesea/qzb9fo5t/

I use 2 div inside the wrapper: one for the article, one for the two backgrounds (article__bg). article__bg is set as absolute and z-index negative.
I've added the .row class to article and article__bg to make it works with materializecss grid in the jsfiddle.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.article {
}

.article__bg {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.article__bg__leftside {
  background: #d27156;
  height: 100%;
}
.article__bg__rightside {
  background: #e3b2b0;
  height: 100%;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="row article">
            <!-- Article -->
            <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
                <a href="">
                    <h4>FIRST TEST</h4>
                </a>

                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam lacinia sed augue in imperdiet. Phasellus tristique velit nec suscipit egestas. Morbi tristique nisl vitae dolor porta pulvinar. Maecenas at ante sit amet massa maximus
                    sagittis eget dictum sem. Sed porta blandit mauris vel vestibulum. Sed consequat sed turpis dapibus iaculis. Praesent venenatis felis tincidunt dictum sollicitudin. Donec egestas vulputate aliquam. Donec eu lacus vehicula ipsum
                    tincidunt dictum. Donec tincidunt iaculis metus non ornare. Nulla at neque semper, interdum est eu, tincidunt nunc. Maecenas dapibus, magna eget tincidunt venenatis, mi odio blandit leo, quis varius sapien ex et mauris. </p>
                <p> Integer augue dui, imperdiet vitae eleifend in, porta et urna. Duis ut pellentesque libero, nec consectetur massa. Donec in eros id arcu scelerisque interdum lacinia hendrerit erat. Praesent eget euismod erat. Praesent viverra placerat
                    neque, sit amet auctor orci tincidunt in. Nam fermentum mauris eu magna maximus, luctus pellentesque arcu blandit. Integer fermentum vestibulum lorem a convallis. Cras maximus erat vel massa dignissim molestie. Nulla sit amet nibh
                    diam. Maecenas mauris dui, iaculis ut nisl sed, hendrerit blandit neque. Maecenas augue eros, posuere id erat a, scelerisque porttitor nisl. Nulla a ex sit amet massa pretium placerat eu sed ipsum. Aenean blandit id dui ut volutpat.
                </p>
                <p> Cras sit amet malesuada justo. Ut suscipit, quam eget rutrum sodales, nunc elit vestibulum risus, eu iaculis augue metus accumsan sem. Mauris aliquam, elit at tristique luctus, enim arcu rhoncus sem, eu euismod eros odio non tortor.
                    Quisque eleifend consectetur magna, nec aliquet quam scelerisque vitae. Integer porttitor eros vulputate, vehicula ante non, tincidunt sem. Sed rutrum tempor pulvinar. Duis lacinia tincidunt nisi nec tincidunt. Nullam consequat
                    nulla nibh, et bibendum odio imperdiet imperdiet. </p>
                <p> Suspendisse sollicitudin mi sed orci tristique porta. Aenean purus sapien, ultricies sit amet cursus quis, hendrerit sit amet neque. Sed sit amet sem maximus, scelerisque urna a, posuere augue. Donec varius libero et mi commodo, non
                    faucibus metus venenatis. Nullam dapibus aliquam lorem eu tincidunt. Sed sit amet varius tortor. Pellentesque diam ante, dictum quis ex in, pulvinar placerat libero. Aenean nulla sem, congue et elementum eu, dapibus et ligula.
                    Duis sed elit hendrerit, eleifend nunc in, imperdiet ex. Sed eu lectus tortor. Nunc quis dolor at orci luctus ullamcorper. Mauris rutrum dolor et turpis vehicula pulvinar. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
                    montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque aliquet, lectus at rutrum efficitur, nisi velit rutrum lacus, vitae lobortis augue ex consequat urna. </p>

                <p> Praesent eu iaculis neque, non dapibus est. Phasellus dignissim venenatis consequat. Phasellus urna justo, euismod ut facilisis sed, semper at augue. Maecenas lacinia placerat mattis. Mauris vel venenatis felis. Sed volutpat libero
                    ut odio rutrum viverra. Pellentesque tempor nunc sit amet massa porta lobortis. Praesent feugiat bibendum sapien. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur vel augue vitae
                    quam volutpat dignissim. Sed scelerisque porta erat at sagittis. Integer accumsan velit vel diam luctus, nec pretium justo vestibulum. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- article -->

        <div class="row article__bg">
            <!-- Leftside background -->
            <div class="col s8 article__bg__leftside">
            </div>

            <!-- Rightside background -->
            <div class="col s4 article__bg__rightside">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- wrapper -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution playing with absolute position and z-index of the backgrounds.

```css
.col.s8.leftside {
    background: #E3B2B0;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.col.s4.rightside {
    position: absolute;
    background: #D27156;
    height:100%;
    width: 60%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Leftside background -->
<div class="col s8 leftside">
</div>
<!-- Rightside background -->
<div class="col s4 rightside">
</div>
<!-- Article -->
<div class="col s6 offset-s3 article">
  <a href="<?php echo $page->permalink(); ?>">
    <h4 id="pageTitle" class="white-text">
      <?php echo $page->title(); ?>
    </h4>
  </a>
  <?php if ($page->coverImage()) : ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $page->coverImage(); ?>" />
  <?php endif ?>
  <!-- Full content -->
  <?php echo $page->content(); ?>
</div>
```